# Clockwise Print of a 4X4 matrix in c

Tags: c, matrix

hi I am trying to print a 4 x 4 matrix in clockwise direction,

Input:

```
1  2  3  4
12 13 14 5
11 16 15 6
10 9  8  7
```

Expected output is:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16`

My code is:

```
 int MAXR=3,MAXC=3,MINR=0,MINC=0;

 while(MINR < MAXR && MINC < MAXC)
    {
        for(i=MINC;i<=MAXC;i++)
        {
            printf("%d  ",arr[MINR][i]);
        }

        for(j=MINR+1;j<=MAXR;j++)
        {
            printf("%d  ",arr[j][MAXC]);
        }

        for(i=MAXC-1;i>=MINC;i--)
        {
            printf("%d  ",arr[MAXR][i]);
        }

        MINR++;
        if((MINR%2)==0)
        {
            MINC=MINC+2;
        }
        //MAXR--;
        //MAXC--;
        //printf("\nMAXR=%d MINR=%d\n",MAXR,MINR);
        for(j=MAXR-1;j>MINR;j--)
        {
            printf("%d  ",arr[j][MINC]);
        }

        MAXR--;
        MAXC--;
    }
```

---

But output is:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 11

Please help me to fix the bug!
Thanks!

output is:

Comment: is your debugger broken?

Comment: @MitchWheat And his `indent` tool too... :'(

Comment: if 4x4 is fixed (because your hardware is like that) i would not bother with the loops and just put either 16 `printfs` or preferably one array with the lookup indices...

Comment: see ==>  http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/

Comment: possible duplicate of [A c program to traverse a n\*n matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239551/a-c-program-to-traverse-a-nn-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have fixed your defect by now. But it was a fun spec, so here is my version:

gcc (GCC) 4.7.3:  gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 spiral.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int matrix[4][4] = {
    {  1,  2,  3,  4 },
    { 12, 13, 14,  5 },
    { 11, 16, 15,  6 },
    { 10,  9,  8,  7 } };

  int edge = sizeof(matrix[0]) / sizeof(int) - 1;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

  printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
  for (int c = 0; c < edge; ++c) { printf("%d ", matrix[i][++j]); }

  while (0 < edge) {
    for (int c = 0; c < edge; ++c) { printf("%d ", matrix[++i][j]); }
    for (int c = 0; c < edge; ++c) { printf("%d ", matrix[i][--j]); }
    --edge;
    for (int c = 0; c < edge; ++c) { printf("%d ", matrix[--i][j]); }
    for (int c = 0; c < edge; ++c) { printf("%d ", matrix[i][++j]); }
    --edge;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My approach was to write out the sequence of required changes to `i` and `j` and find the pattern. What I found was that the pattern appeared after the first line, so I did that as a separate initial step.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help you to print of a matrix of any size (rows/cols) clockwisely.

```
void printMatrixClockwisely(int** numbers, int rows, int columns)
{
    if(numbers == NULL || columns <= 0 || rows <= 0)
        return;

    int start = 0;

    while(columns > start * 2 && rows > start * 2)
    {
        PrintMatrixInCircle(numbers, columns, rows, start);

        ++start;
    }
}

void printNumber(int number)
{
    printf("%d\t", number);
}

void PrintMatrixInCircle(int** numbers, int columns, int rows, int start)
{
    int endX = columns - 1 - start;
    int endY = rows - 1 - start;

    // print a row from left to right
    for(int i = start; i <= endX; ++i)
    {
        int number = numbers[start][i];
        printNumber(number);
    }

    // print a col from up to down
    if(start < endY)
    {
        for(int i = start + 1; i <= endY; ++i)
        {
            int number = numbers[i][endX];
            printNumber(number);
        }
    }

    // print a row from right to left
    if(start < endX && start < endY)
    {
        for(int i = endX - 1; i >= start; --i)
        {
            int number = numbers[endY][i];
            printNumber(number);
        }
    }

    // print a col from down to up
    if(start < endX && start < endY - 1)
    {
        for(int i = endY - 1; i >= start + 1; --i)
        {
            int number = numbers[i][start];
            printNumber(number);
        }
    }
}
```